# How to get time zone value like -0400

Tags: android, timezone

I want to pass date value in my rest service like this

```
"ActionTime":"\/Date(928164000000-0400)\/
```

My question is how to get the `date` and time `zone` value for this `ActionTime` variable.

Comment: feedback plz. ???? problem solved or not yet ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I am doing it:

```
Date dt = new Date();
        int z = dt.getTimezoneOffset();

        String date = "/Date(" + dt.getTime() + z+")/";
```

Thanks for all the help but I have got some what simpler approach for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
Log.d("Time zone","="+tz.getDisplayName());
```

or you can also use this

```
Timezone.getDefault()
```

===================================

```
String s = "2013-01-01 12:00:00";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"));
Date timestamp = null;
try {
    timestamp = df.parse(s);
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    System.out.println(df.format(timestamp));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

===============
You should be able to calculate the difference based on the TimeZone getOffset() value, [see this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getOffset%28long)